# Некорректная вёрстка в профиле сети, в разделе "Сообщества"

Tags: дефект, локализация, дизайн, профиль-участника

В русскоязычном SO есть проблема с разделением двух кнопок в Профиле сети в разделе "Сообщества".

EN_SO

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

RU_SO

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

100% она наблюдается в Firefox 66 и Chrome 73.

Можно слово "Редактировать" заменить на "Изменить",

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или кнопки сделать друг под другом.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Писал об этом в прошлом году на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316702/339911)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Но костыль хотя бы воткнуть стоит,  в виде замены слова. [Предложил перевод на Traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/string/7324).

Comment: @Arhad костыль утвердил. Теперь, видимо, вообще никогда фиксить не будут этот момент.